# Trouble clearing spinner data android

Tags: android, spinner

I have a problem with my spinners in my android app. I have two spinners implemented. Both loads contents from json. The first one look as,

```
    // Code for First spinner
    loc = json.getJSONArray("location");
    for(int i = 0; i < loc.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = loc.getJSONObject(i);
        //put json obkject on variable
        String l = c.getString("stock_location");
        locationList.add(l);
    // Set Spinner Adapter
    location.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>OfferedDiesel.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,locationList));
    // Spinner on item click listener
    location.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {  
        place = locationList.get(position);  
        selected = place;
        new LoadProduct().execute();
        product_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        product.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
         place = null;

   }
   });                  
   }

//Following is the LoadProduct
private class LoadProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(OfferedDiesel.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
         }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.getProductFromLocation(selected);
            return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml            
            /*LOcate site node*/
            try{
                if(json.has("error_msg")){
                    String err = json.getString("error_msg");
                    alert.showAlertDialog(OfferedDiesel.this, "ALert !!", err, null);
                }else{
                    prod = json.getJSONArray("product");

                    for(int i = 0; i < prod.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject d = prod.getJSONObject(i);
                        //put json obkject on variable
                        String k = d.getString("stock_name");
                        productList.add(k);

                        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OfferedDiesel.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,productList);
                        // Set Spinner Adapter
                        product.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                         // Spinner on item click listener
                        product.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {  
                             good = locationList.get(position);  


                                  //selected = place;

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                        place = null;

                                    }
                                });                     
                    }
                }

            }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }/*End of Spinner Populate*/
```

Here, whenever I am selecting a new item in above spinner it will execute `new LoadProduct().execute();` and on my second spinner I am getting the data but the date are appended. I mean for example if by defalt '1' on my first spiner then at second spinner I will get "First" and when I select '2' (change on first spinner) then I will get "Second" it is appended on 'First' and Hence I get 2 items "First" and "Second" instead of just one i.e'Second'. I now need to clear all the spinner list before loading the new. For both spinners I am using json to load data. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code to your `LoadProduct` is the key to understanding the problem.

Comment: I have updated with LoadProduct

Comment: Clear productList before calling asynctask inside first spinner item selection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a few guesses here about what you are trying to do, because I'm not 100% sure I understood... Here's what I think you are trying to do:

1. There are two `ListView`s.
2. When you click on the first one, it sets up text in the second one to load.
3. It does so via an `AsyncTask` called `LoadProduct`.
4. `selected` is used in the `LoadProduct` to determine what to load.
5. You aren't getting quite the results you expect.

Okay, so if I'm right here, I would suggest a few changes.

1. Pass in the selected value to the AsyncTask.
2. Clear the previous adapter from it's values.
3. Add the new values.

The AsyncTask should be able to take the input, no problem.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to clear array list using clear method before adding new data to array,this would defiantly help you